# Proof that Linear maps are isomorphic to matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Below I have added the relevant parts of the lecture notes that are necessary for the proof:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

I have to check that the map $I$ is bijective but I don't know how they did it here, can somebody explain it? I only not understand the bijectivity part of the proof but I could understand why the map is linear so I did not add it in the picture.

EDIT: What I don't understand about this proof is that it says for every linear map there is a family and given a linear map there is only one corresponding unique family. Apparently this person talks about a map that goes from $\{a_{(j,i)}\in \text{F}:j\in\{1,...,m\}\times\{1,...,n\}=\mathcal{M}(m,n,F)$ to $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ with $(a_{j,i})\mapsto \sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ji}A_{v_{i}w_{j}}$ but this map cannot be $I$ because the domain and the codomain does not match up. Please help me, I am really confused

coordinates

[image: coordinates]

Comment: For a linear map, which you've already understood here, a map is injective if and only if its kernel (nullspace) is trivial (contains only the zero vector).  There's also a simple condition using dimensions that you might want to apply for *surjectvity*.

Comment: I can understand what you mean but I want to understand what exactly my professor meant in the script

Comment: Each choice of ordered bases for both $V$ and $W$ determines an isomorphism  (of vector spaces) from $M(m,n,F)$ to $\mathscr L(V,W)$.  You already would know how that isomorphism is constructed in order to understand why it is a linear map.

Comment: Assume I have not understood the linearity, in the script my professor wrote that : $\{A_{v_{i}w_{j}}:(j,i)\in\{1,...,m\}\times \{1,...,n\}\}$ forms a basis, we know that every linearcombination of basisvectors define exactly one element in the vectorspace we are dealing with, in this case this is $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ I don't understand the following sentence and moreover how he concludes from that that the map $I$ is surjective and injective. I have eddited the question, so you can see on the bottom our how we defined the the notion of coordinates.

Comment: We know that the map $I$ is well-defined, because for every $v\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ there exists a family $(a_{ji})$ such that $v=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ji}a_{v_{i}w_{j}}$ because $\mathcal{B}=\{A_{v_{i}w_{j}}:(j,i)\in\{1,...,m\}\times \{1,...,n\}\}$ is a generating system of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$, we also know that those $(a_{ji})$ are unique due to the linear independence of $\mathcal{B}$. With these two statements how can we prove step by step the injectivity and the surjectivity of the map $I$?

Comment: My toughtprocess is: the proof for surjectivity given some matrix i.e. a family $(a_{ji})$ then $\sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ji}A_{v_iw_j}$ is a preimage, therefore surjectivity is proved. Now again given $(a_{ji})$ how can I prove that the preimage is unique, ie show that $I(v)=I(w)\Rightarrow v=w$?

Comment: Here is my try to prove the injectivity. I am sure that I am corect but if you think I am not then please tell me: We look at an element of the imageset, since we have already proved surjectivity we know that $\text{Im}(I)=\mathcal{M}(m,n,F)$ so we pick $(a_{ij})$, then one solution or one preimage is $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{ij}Av_iw_j$ If we now look at a $w\neq v$ with $w=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^n a'_{ij}Av_iw_j$ (we know such $(a'_{ij})$ exist because $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis)  then $a_{ij}\neq a'_{ij}$ for at least one $(j,i)$. Thus preimage unique and therefore injectivity of A

Comment: The only question that remains if that's exactly the proof my professor intendet to conduct and only stated the inferred version of it